# POST 500 Internal Server Error ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to plot some graphs using data from my database in my ASP.NET MVC web application. 
I keep getting

> POST 500 internal server error

Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/Ord2",
                        data: { a: date, b: city },
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,

                    success: function (msg) {
                        //plot 
}
    })
```

Home is my controller name. Ord2 is my method. I am passing two parameters which i am taking as input from user to the same method.

It seems to be working fine when i deploy it on my local IIS but whenever i upload it onto my server, its not working.

I don't have much experience with ASP or jQuery. So please let me know if more info needs to be provided.

Error list:
*UPDATE*

```
POST myurl/Home/Ordx 500 (Internal Server Error)
m.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
m.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
makeGraphs @ VehicleOrders:157
(anonymous function) @ VehicleOrders:144
m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
```

Comment: I would say that the URL is wrong or its an error in the controller.  On your PC when running with Visual Studio off http://localhost/Home/Ord2 it works.  But when deployed onto your server you need the website url   yourserverwebsite/Home/Ord2.  You need the root url in the ajax call.  Other advice is to open up developer tools (Chrome for example) and look at any errors that might be logged in the console window.  And consider downloading Telerik Fiddler to see what's going on too.

Comment: Yes i am visiting the proper links. Everything else in the page is displayed except for my graphs.

I have attached the errors as best i could.

Comment: jQuery itself is not found in your app. Please fix the issue first. Reference jQuery correctly!

Comment: Thats the thing, i have included this:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Still there seems to be a problem.

Comment: I have updated the error list.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution myself. 
The problem was that the date time i was sending to my controller and comparing with the current date time (Server datetime) were not matching.
So i fixed their format and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What would the date time have to do with it?